# How to access kubernetes cluster using masterurl

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I am trying to connect to kubernetes cluster using master url. However, I encounter an error when attempting the following command

Command: `config, ConfigErr clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("https://192.168.99.100:8443","")`

Error: `Get "https://192.168.99.100:8443/api/v1/namespaces": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

Has anyone else encountered this and/or know how to solve this error?

Comment: Do pass the `token` and `ca.crt` to your Kubernetes client? This seems to be an issue.

Comment: how do i do that? buildconfigfromflags takes masterlurl and kubeconfig path only

Comment: how are you trying to connect to the k8s server. Using kubectl, curl, browser?

Comment: i am getting config from buildconfigfromflags and ```kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)``` doing this to connect

Answer (score 2):

Get the kube-apiserver endpoint by describing the service

```
kubectl describe svc kubernetes
```

This will list the endpoint for your APIServer like this:

```
Endpoints:         172.17.0.6:6443
```

Get the token to access the APIServer like this:

```
TOKEN=$(kubectl get secret $(kubectl get serviceaccount default -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}') -o jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode )
```

Query the APIServer with the retreived token:

```
curl -v https://172.17.0.6:6443/api/v1/nodes -k  --header "Authorization:Bearer $TOKEN" --insecure
```

Comment: i have multiple clusters.. so i want to pass different masterurls and access all the clusters...

Comment: For accessing multiple clusters URL's , you must set right context before invoking these operations. For more information on contexts please refer https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/

Answer (score 0):

```
config, ConfigErr = clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags(masterurl,"")
        config.BearerToken=token
        config.Insecure=true
```

use this code to make it work.it worked for me